# get open file whose name is same as directory in bash

Tags: bash, alias

How can I achieve the following in bash? Open a *.cpp file whose name is the same as the current directory?
I tried

alias zv='
myvar =$(basename PWD)
vi $myvar .cpp
'

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this;

```
 alias zv='vi "$(basename "$(pwd)").cpp"'
```

The `"$(..)"` will execute the `pwd` inside the brackets parsing it to basename

The expression format

```
 MYVAR=something someprogram
```

works to set an environment variable within a single execution of a program, but it does not work to create a regular variable as you are doing it -- you would need to split it up in multiple statements, or just do the whole parsing in one statement as my example

Comment: That'll work, but I'd recommend using `$()` instead of backquotes, and putting double-quotes around all filenames and such in case there are any funny characters i them: `alias zv='vi "$(basename "$(pwd)").cpp"'`

Answer (score 0):

is that a space between the `r` and the dot `.` ? in `$myvar .cpp` 
because it's not supposed to be there :P